# NameError: name '??' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, nameerror

I have a simple code as below.

```
finished = True

def number():
    x = int(input("Please enter a number \n"))
    m = x%2

if m>0:
    print("Odd")
    finished = True
else: 
    print("Even")
    finished = True

while finished:
    number()
```

When I run the code, it shows a problem

```
at line 6: if m > 0:
NameError: name 'm' is not defined.
```

would like to know how can I solve this?

Comment: Define `m` before you use it?

Comment: Did you intend for everything after `def number():` to be part of that function? If so, you need to fix your indentation.

Comment: What's with the title of your question?

Comment: may i know which indentation has to be fixed? I have the NameError problem.

Comment: Only the indented lines under the `def number():` line are part of the function.  None of your other code is aware of variables defined inside a function.  You might find [this section of the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) helpful in understanding what is happening here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just move your if statement in your function.

```
def number():
    x = int(input("Please enter a number \n"))
    m = x%2
    if m>0:
        print("Odd")
        finished = True
    else: 
        print("Even")
        finished = True
```